# Is it possible to put elasticsearch indexed data into hdfs?

Tags: elasticsearch, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

Can elastic search indexed data be put into HDFS. Not sure about the fact so thought to get expert view on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain exactly what you are looking for. If you want to backup/restore data into HDFS from Elasticsearch the answer is answer is the Hadoop HDFS snapshot/restore plugin for Elasticsearch:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/tree/master/repository-hdfs

This allows you to back up and restore data from ES into HDFS.

If on the other hand you want to run MapReduce jobs in Hadoop that access Elasticsearch data the answer is Elasticsearch for Apache Hadoop:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/index.html

Comment: Thanks john. I am looking whether the data from HDFS can be indexed in hdfs itself for elasticsearch.

Comment: You would have to read the data out of HDFS and index it into Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch stores it's data in Lucene index file segments, I'm not aware of any way to get around that.